# I cannot talk to Lambert on Witcher 3's Ugly Baby mission

Tags: the-witcher-3

I got this mission:

> Talk to Lambert about journeying to the Circle of Elements

But when I approach Lambert, it just says "Geralt"?

I don't know if it's a bug or if I'm missing anything.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you already talked with Eskel? Try doing another part of the quest first.

If you already did, [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/350532536099037710/) was started by someone with possibly the exact same problem, and [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/350532536099037710/#c350532795334260017) discusses what ultimately helped them (the helpful part is probably the last paragraph):

> I finally got it to work, no bug - my fault kinda. I started the chain and spoke to Lambert, went to where I thought the circle was and couldn't find it. I crossed back over the river and went up the other side but no matter what I did I couldn't get up far enough to the quest marker - I gave up.
>
> I left the game for a good many months, came back to it recently [..] So I went and completed the other quest and fixed Yen's scope. I had forgotten what I had already done a few months before - but it was still showing the marker above Lambert's head.
>
> After rereading this and watching a YouTube video I found an ogre that I hadn't remembered in a cave, but I did remember the boat journey - so I ran all the way back around the lake to the cave, when there realigned the quest pathing - follwed that, killed the ogre, spoke nicely to some rock trolls - completed the ritual.... etc., etc., etc. So yeah, my fault - but I don't think the signposting for the quest was that great.

Comment: I appreciate you took the time to finding that thread and answering.. +1, but the steps to solve it were not clear. I'm back to this game after a while and I don't have the context anymore.. I gave up :) But thanks again!